# Vedo l'oceano nei tuoi occhi anche se non sono blu

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> Vedo l’oceano nei tuoi occhi anche se non sono blu.

Sotto l'aspetto sintattico, in che modo, se c'è, nella frase di cui sopra è possibile capire che 'non sono blu' si riferisce agli occhi e non alla persona che dice la frase medesima?

Secondo me, il problema nasce dal fatto che blu non ha plurale, che se l'avesse l'ambiguità sarebbe risolta.

Comment: La domanda verte su come sia possibile modificare la frase per risolvere l'ambiguità - come l'ha intesa randomatlabuser - o sulla eventuale presenza di un indicatore che possa risolvere l'ambiguità senza ricorrere alla semantica - come l'avrei interpretata io?

Comment: Come l'hai interpretata tu, @Walter Tross.

Comment: In tal caso no, non c'è alcun modo di disambiguare.

Comment: Credo che l'unico caso in cui ci potrebbe essere ambiguità sarebbe in Avatar. =)

Comment: Suona tanto come una frase presa da un film di Troisi :D

Answer (score 7):

In breve, no. Se non interviene la semantica (che ci fa capire che la contrapposizione ha senso solo attribuendo il colore agli occhi) e l'“enciclopedia” (che ci dice che è più facile che siano gli occhi a essere blu che non una persona che parla) non c'è un modo puramente sintattico per disambiguare. È un fatto ineliminabile che le lingue naturali ammettono delle ambiguità: basta pensare ai due sensi della famosa frase «La vecchia porta la sbarra».

Answer (score 4):

> Sotto l'aspetto sintattico, in che modo, se c'è, nella frase di cui sopra è possibile capire che 'non sono blu' si riferisce agli occhi e non alla persona che dice la frase medesima?

Dal punto di vista sintattico ciò non è possibile. Poiché in italiano non è necessario rendere esplicito il soggetto di una frase, sintatticamente parlando non c'è modo di capire se "blu" si riferisca agli occhi o alla persona che pronuncia la frase.

A rendere le cose ancora più complicate contribuiscono altri due elementi:

1. L'aggettivo "blu" non varia da singolare a plurale, come giustamente dici tu
2. "sono", nel verbo essere, viene usato sia nella prima persona singolare che nella terza plurale.

A livello di analisi grammaticale, logica e del periodo, entrambe le interpretazioni sono quindi corrette.

La parola magica in questo caso è **contesto**: è solamente dal contesto che capisci che "blu" si riferisce agli occhi. Se così non fosse, la frase non avrebbe senso.

Answer (score 2):

L'ambiguità può esser risolta ponendo

```
«vedo l’oceano nei tuoi occhi anche se **questi** non sono blu»
```

nel caso si intenda far riferimento agli occhi, oppure

```
«vedo l’oceano nei tuoi occhi anche se **io** non sono blu»
```

nel caso si intenda far riferimento all'io narrante.

Alternativamente:

```
«vedo l’oceano nei tuoi occhi benché non siano blu», per il primo caso;

«vedo l’oceano nei tuoi occhi benché io non sia blu», per il secondo caso.
```

Comment: Anche se non stiamo rispondendo all'OP, la modifica più semplice, più corretta e meno forzata sarebbe dire «...anche se non sono azzurri», visto che dell'aggettivo “blu” si tende ad abusare, anche per influsso dell'inglese, il cui “blue” copre uno spettro molto più ampio del “blu” dell'italiano, che conosce anche almeno “celeste” e “azzurro”.